# Checking inside dynamically modified iframe with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a page that includes a third party script (Xsolla login). This script modifies elements on the page, one of the particular elements being iframe.

- First a placeholder element is inserted
- Then the iframe is deleted and new iframe is inserted with different dynamically loading content
- Both iframes have the same id

How one can detect when the second, replaced, iframe is correctly loaded as Cypress `cy.get()` grabs the first iframe and then never detects newly changed content within the replaced iframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until) plugin and then write a custom check function that inspects deep into the iframe.

```js
/**
 * Because Xsolla does dynamic replacement of iframe element, we need to use this hacky wait.
 */
function checkLoadedXsollaIframe(doc: Document): bool {
  try {
    const iframe = doc.getElementById('XsollaLoginWidgetIframe') as any;
    if(!iframe) {
      return false;
    }
    // This element becomes available only when Xsolla has done its magic JS loading
    const usernameInput = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
    return usernameInput !== null;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}


context('Login', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit(frontendURL);
  });

  it('Should login with valid credentials', () => {

    // This injects Xsolla <script> tag and then
    // this third party script takes its own course of actions 
    cy.get('.login-btn').first().click();

    cy.waitUntil(() => cy.document().then(doc => checkLoadedXsollaIframe(doc)), {timeout: 5000 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the snippet that waits for the content inside the iframe to be loaded and HTMLElements be available & no timeouts required.

```js
const iframeElement = (selector) => {
  const iframe = cy.get(selector);
  return iframe
    .should(($iframe) => // Make sure its not blank
      expect($iframe.attr('src')).not.to.include('about:blank')
    )
    .should(($iframe) => 
    expect($iframe.attr('src')).not.to.be.empty) // Make sure its not empty
    .then(($inner) => {
      const iWindow = $inner[0].contentWindow;
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(iWindow);
      });
    })
    .then((iWindow) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        iWindow.onload = () => { // Listen to onLoad event
          resolve(iWindow.document);
        };
      });
    })
    .then((iDoc) => {
      return cy.wrap(iDoc.body); // Wrap the element to access Cypress API
    });
};
```

Now access the element inside the iframeDocument

```js
iframeElement('#my-iframe') // Grab the iframe
  .find('h2')
  .should('have.text', 'My header text'); //Assert iframe header
```

> **Note:** Don't attempt to access CORS websites. It might fail due to
> security reasons